# Django forms: submission with mixed requests (get and post)

Tags: django, forms, url, request

for seo related reason in my project i have to trap certain search parameters within the url for the "beautiful url" thing.

The advanced search is composed by 7 parameters, 3 of which are location-related and are the ones interesting our seo consultant.

So, now i'm a bit confused. It's been a while since i started using django professionally, but never had to face an issue like this. Basically, the final url structure must be something like this:

```
/Italy/Lombardy/Milan/?price=100&miles=10&last_posted=2
```

and my urls.py is

```
'/(?P<country>\w+)/(?P<zone>\w+)/(?P<city>\w+)/$', SearchView.as_view()
```

now, what i'm not sure about is how should i specify my request in the form method to be able to use that exact url schema? POST or GET? And how can i compose the url for the "action" attribute dynamically while the user types? Is this even the correct solution? I'm really confused about it, any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to change the action field of the form using script, yes. and set the method to GET, and include in the form only the fields appearing in the query string.

Comment: yeah, my form has names as the query string parameters. just i never trapped GET parameters with this url structure (/param1/param2/?param3 and so on). To respect our particular url structure (which is very strict) i should (just an idea) modify the form action attribute to one of the accepted url, so i need to modify that parameter while the user completes the form

Comment: I understand the problem now. A question: for these pretty URLs to be picked up by web crawlers, they have to be linked to from somewhere. Otherwise how do web crawlers know that they need to index Italy/Lombardy/Milan and not any other country/region/city combination? what does your SEO expert say about this?

Comment: that is already sorted out, actually. please focus on the main problem, which is: how do i setup my search form to have a mixed POST/GET request to obtain that url?